# Make the web.config dynamic

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, web.config-transform

We have an application and it is deployed across different pipeline dedicated for various release.

For ex - pipeline A - dedicated for march release
pipeline B - for June release etc

Within each pipeline we various environment like DEV, SIT etc

Now , with release , while deploying code , we need to make changes in the webcofig file , because the urls that we have in config are pipeline and environment dependent.

For Example we have a web server - box 1 for dev environment .
we have Pipeline A , Pipeline B deployed as websites. The web.config of pipeline A will look like -

```
<configMap hostnameList="box1" name="DevEnvironment">
      <include set="Dev" />
</configMap>
<configSet name="Dev">
<add key="someUrl" value="http://somapp-piplelineA-Dev.app.com"/>
</configSet>
```

The web.config of pipeline B will look like -

```
<configMap hostnameList="box1" name="DevEnvironment">
      <include set="Dev" />
</configMap>
<configSet name="Dev">
<add key="someUrl" value="http://somapp-piplelineB-Dev.app.com"/>
</configSet>
```

If you see this config , in the value for key someurl , the pipelineA was changed to pipelineB. These changes are tiresome when there are a lot of keys. So, we want to create a single web.config that can be used by all environment and which would not require any change.

Answer (score 4):

With [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/) you can deploy your web applications semi- or fully-automatically. But also it can perform [Web.config Transformation](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Configuration+files) for each environment separately.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [config transforms ability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx) built in inside visual studio

if you create a new asp .net web project you will see a sample inside `web.debug.config` and `web.release.config`.

you can also right click on `web.config` and click Add Config Transform and you will have a config transform file for each of your build configurations.

you can also use [SlowCheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5). it is a very handy extension.

Comment: By default, Web.config Transformation works only for Configuration Mode (Debug, Release, etc.) and doesn't work well with Environments (sort of orthogonal concept). For example, on Dev you may want to publish Debug and on Staging - Release.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I implemented to allow us to have the config dynamically created depending on the build type, utilizing build events.

Which will allow you to have 1 config to rule them all :)

https://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/

**Project Description**

XmlPreprocess is a command-line utility that can modify annotated XML files much like a code preprocessor. It is useful for deploying configuration files to different environments making substitutions such as connection strings. It is easily integrated into almost any script, build tool or deployment package to simplify and centralize your deployment strategy.

**My build event**

```
C:\XMLPreprocessor\XmlPreprocess.exe /i "C:\AppConfig\Core.config" /dbkind mssql /db "Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DB1;User Id=dbreader; Password=pass1;" /e $(ConfigurationName)
```

This is an example of my configuration XML file the {} params are retrieved from a SQL configuration database which contains the release type (1=Debug,2=Test,3=Release) and the values are populated accordingly.

```
<Nini>
     <Section Name="AppSettings">
      <!-- ifdef _xml_preprocess -->
      <!--
     <Key Name="RSAKeyStrength" Value="${RSAKeyStrength}"/>
        <Key Name="EventLog_Name" Value="{EventLog_Name}"/>
        <Key Name="DomainAddress" Value="${DomainAddress}"/>
        <Key Name="AuthIssuer" Value="${AuthIssuer}"/>
    -->
    <!-- else -->
    <Key Name="RSAKeyStrength" Value="2048"/>
        <Key Name="EventLog_Name" Value="MyApp"/>
        <Key Name="DomainAddress" Value="mydomain.com"/>
        <Key Name="AuthIssuer" Value="auth.domain.com"/>
    <!-- endif -->
  </Section>

  <Section Name="ConnectionStrings">
    <!-- ifdef _xml_preprocess -->
    <!--
    <Key Name="IdentityUserModelEntities" Value="data source=${DB1ConnectionString};MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
        <Key Name="DB1ModelEntities" Value="data source=${DB1ConnectionString};MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
        <Key Name="LoggingDB1Entities" Value="data source=${LoggingDB1ConnectionString};MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
    -->
    <!-- else -->
    <Key Name="IdentityUserModelEntities" Value="data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DB1;user id=admin;password=pass1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
        <Key Name="DB1ModelEntities" Value="data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=DB1;user id=admin;password=pass1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
        <Key Name="LoggingDB1Entities" Value="data    source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LoggingDB1;user id=logging_admin;Password=pass1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
    <!-- endif -->
     </Section>
    </Nini>
```